# How To Get Results For Paid Traffic On Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

am having a bit of trouble with regards to google analytics. I've been searching for clues on how to construct my query to return results for `Paid` Traffic under Traffic Sources-->Search-->Paid but to no avail. Apparently `ga:medium==organic` works as a filter for Organic and according to documentation `ga:medium` only accepts `ppc`, `organic`, `referral` or `(not set)`. Any one knows how to get the results for `Paid` Traffic? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the API, but in the interface the medium for paid traffic is "cpc", so "ga:medium==cpc" should be worth a try (actually I use this when I query GA via Google App script, so I'm pretty  confident it will work).

Comment: thanks you have saved my day, though `ga:medium:cpc` isn't exactly the value but rather `ga:medium==cpc`. I'll accept your answer though.

Comment: Yup, that was me typing before thinking. Fixed in in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's official documentation (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries) the full paid traffic is the following:

```
filters=ga:medium==cpa,ga:medium==cpc,ga:medium==cpm,ga:medium==cpp,ga:medium==cpv,ga:medium==ppc
```

Comment: How about `filters=ga:medium=~^(cpa|cpc|cpm|cpp|cpv|ppc)$`?

Comment: On a different note: doesn't cpm stand for Display traffic and cpa/cpp/cpv for Other-Advertising traffic?

Comment: Both end up still being  paid traffic sources, right?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's "Default Channel Grouping" definition](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en) (under "Paid Search"), you should apply the following filter:

```
filters=ga:medium=~^(cpc|ppc|paidsearch)$;ga:adDistributionNetwork!=Content
```